# Can we reuse an intermediate variable from within a guard inside a match?

Tags: scala

Say I have a method `foo` as:

```
def foo(i:Int):Option[Int] = ??? // some code
```

Now I want to operate on a `Seq` of `Int` as follows:

```
Seq(1, 2).map{
  case int => foo(int)
}.collect{
  case Some(int) => int
}
```

One way to combine this would be to do:

```
Seq(1, 2).collect{
  case int if foo(int).isDefined => foo(int)
}
```

Is there any way I can avoid calling `foo` twice?

So basically I want `foo(int)` to be defined on the LHS of `=>` as a variable ready for use on the RHS rather than having to compute it again.

Comment: `for { i <- ints ; j = i + 1; if j % 2 == 0} yield j` You may use for-comperhension like this

Comment: @jilen i like the above approach.

Answer (score 1):

`foo(int)` only exists within the scope of the `if`, so no. I don't think this is possible. In general, I would probably use something similar to the first block of code you have using `map` and `collect`, as `foo` is only called once in that context.

In some cases it also may be possible to re-phrase the problem altogether. For example here, this can be shortened using `flatMap`:

```
def foo(i: Int): Option[Int] = Option(i).filter(_ > 1)

scala> Seq(1, 2).flatMap(foo)
res0: Seq[Int] = List(2)
```

Answer (score 1):

For the case you gave, if `foo` were a partial function, you could just do

```
Seq(1, 2).collect{foo}
```

Conveniently, we can turn `foo` into such a partial function (defined only where `foo` returns `Some(...)`), using `Function.unlift`

Let's define a suitable `foo`

```
def foo(i:Int) = i match { case 1 => Some(42) ; case _ => None }
```

and test it

```
Seq(1, 2).collect{
  case int if foo(int).isDefined => foo(int)
}
// Seq[Option[Int]] = List(Some(42))
```

Now "unlift" it to a partial function

```
val partialFoo = Function.unlift(foo)
```

and test that:

```
Seq(1, 2).collect{partialFoo}
// Seq[Int] = List(42)
```

So you don't get the value wrapped in `Some(...)`, but I assume you would have unwrapped that anyway since your original code would have had every element in a `Some(...)`