# Avoid duplicated computation in guards

Tags: scala

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.{Calendar, Date, GregorianCalendar}

import com.mongodb.casbah.Imports._
import com.mongodb.casbah.commons.conversions.scala._
case class Quota(date: Date, used: Int)
object MongoDateDemo extends App {
  val client = InsertUsers.getClient
  val db = client("github")
  val quota = db("quota")
  val rand = scala.util.Random
//  quota.drop()
//  (1 to 100).foreach { _ =>
//    quota += DBObject("date" -> new Date(), "used" -> rand.nextInt(10))
//    Thread.sleep(1000)
//  }
  val minuteInMilliseconds = 60 * 1000
  def thresholdDate(minute: Int) = new Date(new Date() .getTime - minuteInMilliseconds * minute) // since a minute ago
  val fields = DBObject("_id" -> 0, "used" -> 1)
  val x = quota.find("date" $gte thresholdDate(28), fields).collect {
    case x if x.getAs[Int]("used").isDefined => x.getAs[Int]("used").get
  }
  println(x.toList.sum)
//  val y = x.map {
//    case dbo: DBObject => Quota(dbo.getAs[Date]("date").getOrElse(new Date(0)), dbo.getAs[Int]("used").getOrElse(0))
//  }
}
```

It's reading documents from a collection and filter out those that don't have "used" defined, then summing up the numbers.

The `x.getAs[Int]("used")` part is duplicated computation, how can I avoid it?

Comment: Possible duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31216940/can-we-reuse-an-intermediate-variable-from-within-a-guard-inside-a-match

Comment: `x` is an iterator.

Comment: You call this [minimal](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not much of a Scala programmer, but isn't that what `flatMap` is for?

```
quota
  .find("date" $gte thresholdDate(38), fields)
  .flatMap(_.getAs[Int]("used").toList)
```

Comment: This won't even compile.

Comment: Fair enough. Though some minimal effort on your part to figure out how `flatMap` applies to your situation may actually yield an answer.

Comment: It doesn't really apply to this situation, IMHO>

Comment: Maybe something like `quotes.map(_.getAs[Int]("used")).flatMap(_.map(x => x))`, i.e. create a list of `Optional`s, then use `flatMap` to extract the values. But even if that works your original code may just be better...

Answer (score 0):

Since this is not possible to avoid, I had to do it in two steps, map into `Option`s then collect. I used `view` method so that the collection is not traversed twice:

```
import java.util.{Calendar, Date, GregorianCalendar}

import com.mongodb.casbah.Imports._
import com.mongodb.casbah.commons.conversions.scala._
case class Quota(date: Date, used: Int)
object MongoDateDemo extends App {
  val client = InsertUsers.getClient
  val db = client("github")
  val quota = db("quota")
  val rand = scala.util.Random
//  quota.drop()
//  (1 to 100).foreach { _ =>
//    quota += DBObject("date" -> new Date(), "used" -> rand.nextInt(10))
//    Thread.sleep(1000)
//  }
  val minuteInMilliseconds = 60 * 1000
  def thresholdDate(minute: Int) = new Date(new Date() .getTime - minuteInMilliseconds * minute) // since a minute ago
  val fields = DBObject("_id" -> 0, "used" -> 1)
  val usedNumbers = quota.find("date" $gte thresholdDate(38), fields).toList.view.map {
    _.getAs[Int]("used")
  }.collect {
    case Some(i) => i
  }.force
  println(usedNumbers.sum)
//  val y = x.map {
//    case dbo: DBObject => Quota(dbo.getAs[Date]("date").getOrElse(new Date(0)), dbo.getAs[Int]("used").getOrElse(0))
//  }
}
```

Comment: Could you not just use `flatMap` instead to avoid the `collect` step?

Comment: I don't think so. Could you post an answer to elaborate?

Comment: An answer in the linked question shows `flatMap(x => Option(x))` style.

Comment: Using `flatMap`instead of `map` will flatten your collection, basically removing any `None` items and unboxing the rest. Something like `...toList.view.flatMap { _.getAs[Int]("used") }` is what I was referring to. It should remove the need for the secondary `collect`, but not being familiar with your code - there may be other optimizations which could be applied as well.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `getAs` returns an Option, this should do what you want:

```
val x = quota.find("date" $gte thresholdDate(28), fields).flatMap { _.getAs[Int]("used") }
```

This is similar to doing this:

```
scala> List(Some(1), Some(2), None, Some(4)).flatMap(x => x)
res: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 4)
```

Or this:

```
scala> (1 to 20).flatMap(x => if(x%2 == 0) Some(x) else None)
res: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20)
```